# changing from long to bytes and vice versa

Tags: programming

I want to converse data from long to bytes and vice versa. After searching around, I sticked together some code, which seems to work *(the same code works for int and floats as well)*.

The long value `LongVal` changes to a byte array, and the four bytes construct `LongVal2`. Obviously `LongVal = LongVal2`.

```
long LongVal = -4080;
long LongVal2;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

//byte* my_function(long LongVal){
//  byte *LongVal_byte = (byte *) & LongVal; 
//  return & (LongVal_byte[0]);
//}

//long my_function2(byte & LongVal_byte){
//  long LongVal2;
//  memcpy(&LongVal2, LongVal_byte, sizeof(LongVal2));
//  return  LongVal2;
//}

void loop(){

  byte *LongVal_byte = (byte *) & LongVal; 
  memcpy(&LongVal2, LongVal_byte, sizeof(LongVal2));
  Serial.println(LongVal2);  
  Serial.println(" ");  

//byte LongVal_byte = my_function(long LongVal);
//LongVal2 = my_function2(byte & LongVal_byte);  

}
```

But should I try to wrap the two first lines of `loop()` in two individual functions, errors occur. The remarked lines are my attempts to create two functions.

How to wrap them up properly?

**EDIT**
This is what appears if I try to use the remarked functions:

```
 In function 'long int my_function2(byte&)':
15:51: error: invalid conversion from 'byte {aka unsigned char}' to 'const void*' [-fpermissive]
25:0,
1:
117:14: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)' [-fpermissive]

 In function 'void loop()':
26:33: error: expected primary-expression before 'long'
27:30: error: expected primary-expression before '&' token
```

Comment: And what do the "errors" say? Hint: they tell you what is wrong - they're not just printed for fun. Read them. They are generally self explanatory.

Comment: @ Majenko That is true, but due to my inexperience to C, I lack to interpreter  them.

Comment: But we can. Or we could if you told us what they were. By the way, I can already see some fundamental misunderstandings and mistakes in your code. I want to marry those up with the error messages you are getting so that you can understand the errors better in the future.

Comment: @ Majenko I just added the error comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many problems here:

1) in function call there shouldn't be types, only arguments. `byte LongVal_byte = my_function(LongVal);`

2) & before variable means "get variable address". However in function prototype `long my_function2(byte & LongVal_byte)` it means reference to passed variable (and it must be byte), not a pointer.

3) pointer to local variable is returned from my_function. It might be working until pointed memory gets rewrited by something else (another function call or so)

And whole code might look like that:

```
long LongVal = -4080;
long LongVal2;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

byte * my_function(long & LongVal) {
  return (byte*)&LongVal;
}

long my_function2(byte * LongVal_byte) {
  return *((long *)LongVal_byte);
}

void loop(){

  byte * LongVal_byte = my_function(LongVal);
  LongVal2 = my_function2(LongVal_byte);  

  Serial.println(LongVal2);  
  Serial.println(" "); 
}
```

But it is basically exactly the same as before without functions (just no need for memcpy)

Comment: @ KIIV It works flawlessly, and even more, it works with every type of variables, *(int, floats, even strings)*, providing that I set in the code the right type of variable.

Answer (score 1):

> 15:51: error: invalid conversion from 'byte {aka unsigned char}' to 'const void*' [-fpermissive]

```
memcpy(&LongVal2, LongVal_byte, sizeof(LongVal2));
```

LongVal_byte is a single byte. It's not a pointer, and `memcpy` expects a pointer.

> 26:33: error: expected primary-expression before 'long'

```
byte LongVal_byte = my_function(long LongVal);
```

You do not specify the variable type when passing a variable to a function. The variable already knows what it is, and the function already knows what it wants.

> 27:30: error: expected primary-expression before '&' token

```
LongVal2 = my_function2(byte & LongVal_byte);
```

Same there.

You are showing a fundamental lack of understanding of some concepts of C.  Other errors you are making:

```
long LongVal2;
...
long my_function2(byte & LongVal_byte){
    long LongVal2;
```

You should never ever re-define a global variable inside a function. It's not actually syntactically incorrect, but from a reading perspective it becomes almost impossible to keep track of *which* `LongVal2` variable is being used at any one time.

```
long my_function2(byte & LongVal_byte){
```

You are passing a reference to a *single* byte, not an array of bytes. For that you need a pointer.

You should re-write your functions to be like this:

```
byte* my_function(long LongVal) {
    return (byte *)&LongVal;
}
```

(although that is completely pointless, you just need to cast the value, you don't need a function to do it:

```
byte *byteval = (byte *)&LongVal;
```

)

```
long my_function2(byte *LongVal_byte){
    long LongVal2;
    memcpy(&LongVal2, LongVal_byte, sizeof(LongVal2));
    return LongVal2;
}
```

That is a long winded, but "safe" way of doing it. It is needed only on CPUs where alignment matters.  On an 8-bit CPU the alignment is 8-bit, and so a 32-bit word can be at any address.  On a 32-bit system a 32-bit word will be at a 4-byte alignment, so that method is needed.  On an 8-bit though you can just cast the array into a long:

```
long *LongValue = (long *)&LongVal_byte;
```

A better solution to the whole thing, though, is to use a union:

```
typedef union {
    byte byteval[4];
    long longval;
} LongBytes;

LongBytes myVal;
```

You can then access:

```
myVal.longval = 4893723284;
```

And also:

```
myVal.byteval[i];
```

where `i` is 0-3.

Comment: @ Majenko Your comments were quite thorough and useful. Thank you for your interest.